# Mysterious nil property in IOS objective C category

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to access a function in an objective C category that extends a UIViewController from the original controller. When I do this one of the properties is nil and the method doesn't work properly. When accessed from inside the category (using a UITapGestureRecogniser) the property has a value in memory and works fine. Am I missing something this seems very odd?

calling from the UIViewController:

```
[self dismissCurrentPopinControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

from the category: (UIViewController_MaryPoppin)

```
- (void)dismissCurrentPopinControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void(^)(void))completion
{
    UIViewController *presentedPopin = self.presentedPopinViewController;
```

The presentedPopin controller is nil when called from outside the category.

Comment: Who knows without seeing the code.

Comment: Without code it sounds like impossible. However, I read something about properties. Are you trying to store something in a category? If so, you can't, you have to subclass it

Comment: Show the code that gets the reference to that view controller instance (i.e. the "external call").

Comment: Its a category so there is no reference it just extends the original view controller with some more methods and properties. so I am just calling [self dismissCurrentPopinControllerAnimated:]

Comment: ok my mistake, the method was being sent to the wrong object. with this category, the message is sent to the presentedController  (in this case a UINavigationController)  rather than the UIViewController doing the presenting. The compiler didn't complain because it still had those methods to call..

Comment: @Md1079 A Category should not store new properties. For this purpose you have to subclass the object

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, it seems that with this category (UIViewController+MaryPoppin) you need to send messages to the presented controller (in this case a UINavigationController) so self was incorrect although the compiler still didn't complain.

```
[self  navigationController]dismissCurrentPopinControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This seems to have solved the problem